# bonus question on quaternions

Tags: analysis

I have this asterisk question, I know its hard to do and I know no one would get it in my class. Just wondering if any of you guys could give me good hints in how to do this. It would be appreciated.

Thank you

Question

The quaternions extend the complex numbers and give non-commutative products on points of $\mathbb{R^4}$. They satisfy every field axiom except for the commutativity of multipication. Show that there is no commutative product making $\mathbb{R^n}$ a field for $n \geq 3$. For $n=2$ the field is the complex numbers.

Comment: A proof can be found on the wiki page of Frobenius theorem for real division algebras. (I've problem to include the link directly).

Comment: Remember [this person](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/64609/mathlover) who is also in your class? It seems they already found a proof and [asked about it](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/323226/856).

Comment: They should really hang out together more ...

Comment: who are these guys, i am going to go find these people. but they are in new zealand when im like 100 000 miles away from them lol